# VisualStudio completion session dismissed when removing completion set

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to extend html completion in VisualStudio IDE. I meed it for framework, that combines html markup with custom expressions. I need to add support for those expressions. Problem is, that when I implement my `CompletionSource` to provide completion for custom elements in the markup there is already one CompletionSet specificly `HtmlCompletionSet` inside completionSets passed AugmentCompletionSession of my `CompletionSource`. I should add I use `[Order(After = "default")]` attribute on `CompletionSourceProvider` to ensure my completion goes after html completion.

The problem is I don't want anything from html completions to show on my custom elements. I want to get rid of whole `HtmlCompletionSet`.

So here is what I tried:

1. fill my own Completion set
2. Add my completion set to completionSets
3. check is `HtmlCompletionSet` is there
4. remove the `HtmlCompletionSet`  if there / update the completion set so it is empty

This results in completion session disapearing. I am guessing it got dismissed automaticaly or something. What should I do? Is there any elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: In general, the CompletionSet APIs aren't really designed for "replace the existing thing"; their model is append-only. You may have to specifically ask the HTML editor folks if they have a more specific extension point for this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Problem is I don't know who to contact with these questions.

Comment: Yeah, nor do I to be honest. :-/ Let me send an e-mail internally.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to extend/modify html completion sets is through IHtmlCompletionListProvider to add new items, or through IHtmlCompletionListFilter to filter out existing completion entries. The HtmlCompletionContext passed through to the methods on these interfaces should give you enough context to determine what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am doing this. I am doing where possible. That is if I want to add custom html elements, custom attributes or custom attribute values. `IHtmlCompletionListProvider` and `IHtmlCompletionListFilter` are good for that. How ever, my problem is. That I also need intellisense for custom expressions  that have completely different syntax. That means I have to fire intellisense on different characters, commit on different characters... etc. But still inside same html document.